# Solution of a 2nd order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this differential equation. Any help is highly appreciated.

$$-y'' + m^2 x^2 y = 0,\quad \text{where}\;\; y = y(x)\;\;\text{and}\;\; y'' = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

Even a series solution is okay.

Comment: have you tried variation of parameters?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function

Comment: You might be interested by the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/374123/73025).

Comment: What did you try to compute a series solution?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-y%27%27+%2B+m%5E2x%5E2y%3D0

Answer (score 1):

$-y''+m^2x^2y=0$

$y''-m^2x^2y=0$

Note that this belongs to an ODE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0205.pdf.

Suppose $m\in\mathbb{R}^+$ :

Let $y=e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u$ ,

Then $y'=e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u'-mxe^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u$

$y''=e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u''-mxe^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u'-mxe^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u'+\left(m^2x^2e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}-me^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}\right)u=e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u''-2mxe^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u'+(m^2x^2-m)e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u$

$\therefore e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u''-2mxe^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u'+(m^2x^2-m)e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u-m^2x^2e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u=0$

$e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u''-2mxe^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u'-me^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}u=0$

$u''-2mxu'-mu=0$

You can apply the procedure in [Help on solving an apparently simple differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97586) to get $u=c_1\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\frac{t^2}{4m}+xt}}{\sqrt{t}}dt+c_2\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\frac{t^2}{4m}-xt}}{\sqrt{t}}dt$

$\therefore y=c_1e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\frac{t^2}{4m}+xt}}{\sqrt{t}}dt+c_2e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2}}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\frac{t^2}{4m}-xt}}{\sqrt{t}}dt$

$y=c_1\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\frac{t^2}{4m}+xt-\frac{mx^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{t}}dt+c_2\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\frac{t^2}{4m}-xt-\frac{mx^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{t}}dt$

$y=C_1\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{t^2}{4m}+xt-\frac{mx^2}{2}}~d(\sqrt{t})+C_2\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{t^2}{4m}-xt-\frac{mx^2}{2}}~d(\sqrt{t})$

$y=C_1\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{t^4}{4m}+xt^2-\frac{mx^2}{2}}~dt+C_2\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{t^4}{4m}-xt^2-\frac{mx^2}{2}}~dt$