# Second Order Non-Linear ODE involving Bessel Functions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this but I'm getting nowhere. Does anyone know step-by-step solution? or at least the general techniques to use? I do know that the solution involves the Bessel functions.

$y'' + (1/x)y' - Ay = B$

Where y is differentiated with respect to  x.

Comment: You might want to investigate the [*Method of Frobenius*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) or Infinite Series methods to solve a Bessel equation. You might also want to see the [general solution I wrote [*here*](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374123/help-with-special-function-differential-equation/374333#374333) for this type of equation.

Comment: I'm not an expert in diffeq but shouldn't there be second bessel kind term in the solution as well?

Answer (score 1):

Well,this seems to be a nonhomogeneous Bessel equation.The solution space will be spanned by the fundamental solution of the homogeneous Bessel equation plus an solution to the nonhomogeneous one.
First consider the homogeneous equation:
                       $x^2y''+xy'-Ax^2y=0$

As we all know the fundamental solution to this very Bessel equation is:

$J_v=\sum^{+\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k(1/2x)^{2k}}{\Gamma(k+1)k!}$ where $\Gamma$ is the standard gamma function.

For the detailed process you can just google'first Bessel kind function',but as you may notice there is difference on the coefficients here between the canonical one,I suggest a dialation trick such as let $Y=ay$ where a is to be chosen later to get the canonical equation.

The next step would be searching for a solution to the nonhomogeneous one,which is piece of cake,just let $y=-A/B$.

So the general solution to this problem is:$y=cJ_v-A/B$,where $c$ is constant.