# hypergeometric, Bessel ordinary diff. eq of some sort?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

Take $\mu\neq 0$. I am wondering if anybody has insight on the ode $x^2f''(x)+(2\mu+1)xf'(x)+\mu^2 f(x)=0$ subject to $f(0)<\infty$. Otherwise, we could take $f(x)=x^{-\mu}$. Note this is similar to the hypergeometric equation $x(x-1)y''+\big[(\alpha+\beta+1)x-\gamma\big]y'+\alpha\beta y=0$ with $\alpha=\beta=\mu$. Or could this somehow be related to a Bessel equation?

Comment: You might want to look at my answer here for DEQs of this form: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374123/help-with-special-function-differential-equation/374333#374333

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$ into the differential equation reveals that $(\alpha+\mu)^2=0$.  Thus, with a degenerate solution, both $x^{-\mu}$ and $x^{-\mu} \log{x}$ are solutions.  I am not sure how to construct a solution that is finite at the origin.