# solve $axy''-by'+cxy=0$ step by step

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $$axy''-by'+cxy=0$$ step by step

I know the solution is $$y=k_1x^{u}J_{u}\left(\sqrt{\frac{c}{ a}}x\right)+k_2x^{u}Y_{u}\left(\sqrt{\frac{c}{ a}}x\right)$$

Where $k_1,k_2$ are arbitrary constant, $a,b,c$ are constant,

$$u=\frac{a+b}{2a}$$
And $J_v(x)$ and $Y_v(x)$ are the [Bessel Function of the First Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and  [Bessel Function of the Second Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) respectively.

But I don't know how to derive it.

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374123/help-with-special-function-differential-equation/374333#374333